# Append values with same key PHP MySQL D3

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, d3.js

It might be a silly question, but Im struggling with this.

I need to transform data from mysql database to d3 line chart.

How do I turn this:

```
[{"key":"Branch1","values":["21","1961"]},{"key":"Branch2","values":["21","1961"]},{"key":"Branch2","values":["22","20040"]}]
```

into this:

```
[{"key":"Branch1","values":["21","1961"]},{"key":"Branch2","values":[["21","1961"],["22","20040"]]}]
```

I have a PHP function that creates the first result. Here is the function

```
function getChartData(){
$currentDate = $this->getCurrentDate();
$query = "select t2.name as 'office', DAY(t1.datetime_created) as 'day', t1.datetime_created as 'date', SUM(t1.amount) as 'amount' FROM money_main_records t1, offices t2 WHERE t1.id_branch = t2.office_id AND MONTH(t1.datetime_created) = ". $currentDate['month_number'] . " GROUP BY t2.name, DAY(t1.datetime_created)";
$result =$this->db->query($query);
$series=array();
foreach ($result->result() as $item){
  $serie= array (
     "key" => $item->office,
     "values" => array (
          $item->day,
          $item->amount
      )
  );
  array_push($series,$serie);
}
return $series;
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated!!! Thanks!

Comment: Your question isn't silly. A lot of JS libraries group JSON data (like underscore, lodash, lazy etc.), but not the way you're looking for. This could be helpful to somebody who wants to group data specifically for D3. I'd suggest adding D3 to your title if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this with jQuery.

```js
var data = [{
  "key": "Branch1",
  "values": ["21", "1961"]
}, {
  "key": "Branch2",
  "values": ["21", "1961"]
}, {
  "key": "Branch2",
  "values": ["22", "20040"]
}];

$('#data').html(JSON.stringify(data));

var groupedData = [];

// Iterate through your data
$.each(data, function(index, item) {
  if (groupedData.length > 0) {
    // Check if item exists
    var itemExists = $.grep(groupedData, function(groupItem, groupIndex) {
      return groupItem.key == item.key;
    });

    // If item doesn't exist, add it
    if (itemExists.length == 0) {
      groupedData.push({
        key: item.key,
        values: [item.values]
      });
    }
    // Otherwise, append it to existing item's values array
    else {
      var valuesToAdd = [];
      $.each(item.values, function(valIndex, value) {
        valuesToAdd.push(value);
      });

      itemExists[0].values.push(valuesToAdd);
    }
  } else {
    groupedData.push({
      key: item.key,
      values: [item.values]
    });
  }
});

$('#groupedData').html(JSON.stringify(groupedData));

console.log('-- Grouped --');
console.log(groupedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>

Your JSON:
<br/>
<br/>
<div id='data'></div>

<hr/>JSON You want:
<br/>
<br/>
<div id='groupedData'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
$data = [];
foreach ($result->result() as $item){
    // Group offices
    $data[$item->office][] = [
                  $item->day,
                  $item->amount
              ];

}

$series = [];
// Browse all offices
foreach($data as $officeKey=>$officeArrays){
    $series[] = ['key'=>$officeKey, 'values'=> $officeArrays];
}

return $series;
```

Could not test my code, and it might not be the best solution, but I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your short reply, it does not do the results requested but shows me different approaches to handling data. Line chart is one way D3 requests data, column, bar and even pie charts requests data different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
$branches = array();

foreach(getChartData() as $branch)
{
   if(empty($branches[$branch['key']]))
    $branches[$branch['key']] = array();

   $branches[$branch['key']] = array_merge($branches[$branch['key']],$branch['values']);
}

echo json_encode(array($branches));
```

It outputs the following:

```
[{"Branch1":["21","1961"],"Branch2":["21","1961","22","20040"]}]
```

Or maybe like this then ? :

```
$branches = array();

foreach(getChartData() as $branch)
{
   if(empty($branches[$branch['key']]))
    $branches[$branch['key']] = array();

   $branches[$branch['key']][] = $branch['values'];
}

echo json_encode(array($branches));
```

Outputs:

```
[{"Branch1":[["21","1961"]],"Branch2":[["21","1961"],["22","20040"]]}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your short reply, it does not do the results requested but shows me different approaches to handling data. Line chart is one way D3 requests data, column, bar and even pie charts requests data different ways.